# JavaScript Цикл for и while отрабатывает по разному, почему?

Tags: javascript

Объясните пжл, почему вот это выполняется с ошибкой (возвращает всегда результат 0):

```
const p = (sent, symbol) => {
  let count = 0;
  for(let i = 0; i< sent.legth; i++) {
    if(sent[i] === symbol) {
      count++ ;
    }
  }
  return console.log(count);
}
p('le идеален дддля', 'д') //тут всегда 0 почему-то
```

А вот это считает правильно:

```
const f = (sent, symbol) => {
  let i = 0;
  let count = 0;
  while(i < sent.length) {
    if(sent[i] === symbol) {
      count++ ;
    }
    i++;
  }
  return console.log(count);
}
f('le идеалендд ддля', 'д') //а тут все правильно, 5
```

Comment: Оформлять код не плохо бы. А то на отвали выкинули каку и убежали

Comment: Все впереди, у меня даже линтер не стоит, просто чесалось быстрее узнать что не так

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Потому что в первом случае написан `legth`, а должен быть `length`

Если бы вы писали код в *IDE*, то спокойно это увидели.

Comment: Даже vscode это распознал бы.

Comment: Десятки раз читал такие темы тут на стаке и думал меня-то такое никогда не постигнет...